# Dynamically adjust Bootstrap layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have kind of a problem. I implement something similar like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-xs-3">Test 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">Test 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3" ng-if="test">Test 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-xs-3">Test 4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">Test 5</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">Test 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I in the most simple way realize, that once i disable the "Test 3" div with `test`the "Test 4" div takes it's place? The real code is more complicated, but basically everything needs to dynamically float left so that no white space gets created.

Comment: keep all of them in one row not seperate..

Comment: Please mark the answer accepted so others know the question is solved.

Answer (score 4):

Put all of the `col-*` in a single `row`..

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">Test 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">Test 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3" ng-if="test">Test 3</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">Test 4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">Test 5</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">Test 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is known as [Bootstrap column wrapping](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping).

Comment: Sometimes it can be so simple :D. Never thought it would work, but yes it did. Thanks.